# putting double value 2d array read text

Tags: java, arrays, file

I want to put my text's double values on 2d array. My text has double and string value like that

**my text**

```
deneme deneme 4.5 5.5 6.6 7.5 9.9 9.9

dsdsa sddsf 9.9 8.7 7.5 8.8 4.4 6.5
```

ı extraxt double value from string. **my program output is**

```
4.5 5.5 6.6 7.5 9.9 9.9 9.9 8.7 7.5 8.8 4.4 6.5
```

how can ı do my output **sextet**. if ı can do this , ı will sort each line

firstline: 4.5 5.5 6.6 7.5 9.9 9.9

secondline:  9.9 8.7 7.5 8.8 4.4 6.5

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> puan;
    puan = okuDiziyeKoy("C:\\deneme\\HW.txt");
    System.out.format("%d kayıt okundu.%n", puan.size());

    for (int j = 0; j < puan.size(); j++) {

        String point = puan.get(j);

        String[] edit = point.split("[\\{\\}\\)]");

        for (String s : edit) {

            String a = s.replaceAll("[\\}\\-\\>\\>\\]\\[\\#\\*\\{]+", "");
            String b = a.replaceAll("[\\.]+", ",");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(b);

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {

                if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {

                    Double doubleValue = scanner.nextDouble();
                    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    numbers.add(doubleValue);
                    // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(numbers.toArray()));

                    final int col = 6;
                    final int rows = numbers.size() % col == 0 ? numbers.size() / col : numbers.size() / col + 1;
                    double[][] deneme = new double[rows][col];
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < col; k++) {
                            if (i == rows - 1 && k >= numbers.size() % col) 
                                break;
                            deneme[i][k] = numbers.get(k + col * i);       
                            System.out.print( deneme[i][k]+ " ");
                        }// for k end
                        System.out.println(); // go to next line
                    } // for i end

                }// if scan end

                else {

                    //if it is string comes value here
                    String stringValue = scanner.next();

                }// if scan end

            }// while end

        }// for string s

    }// for end

}// main end
```

Comment: I will comment here. You may do 'restoring' and 'printing' job outside of `while` or `for` loop, after you get the whole input. Also you need to define `numbers` outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restore the elements into `deneme`, all the elements will be put into `deneme[0]` since `k` is from `0` to `numbers.size() - 1`. You may fix it like below:

```
final int col = 6;
final int rows = numbers.size() % col == 0 ? numbers.size() / col : numbers.size() / col + 1;
double[][] deneme = new double[rows][col];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < col; k++) {
        if (i == rows - 1 && k >= numbers.size() % col) // UPDATE: last line may not contain `col` sized elements
            break;
        deneme[i][k] = numbers.get(k + col * i);       
        System.out.print( deneme[i][k]+ " ");
    }// for k end
    System.out.println(); // go to next line
} // for i end
```

Comment: ı take Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at line deneme[i][k] = numbers.get(k + col * i);

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now! It happens because there are not `col`-sized elements in last row.

Comment: cause of it has else if it is string so if there is string it goes else part.. ı think it couse of else if string part but ı should not delete it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your words.

Comment: sory my english is bad :( but ı try to said. İF you look my code there is else if statement. ı extract double and string if text value is string it goes string statemnt,so after string value, double value can be come. ı update my code know please try it again. So you wil see it still by line by

Comment: @user2583040 You're welcome. Your acceptance of my answer will be a great encouragement for me:)

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a newline after the inner loop(`k` loop), use a `System.out.println()`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < numbers.size(); k++) {
         deneme[i][k] = numbers.get(k + (numbers.size() * i));       
         System.out.print( deneme[i][k]+ " ");
      }// for k end
      System.out.println(); // to introduce a newline
 } // for i end
```

Comment: ı put this code my program its output one under the other number by one by. But ı want to sextet array